# Sharepoint online 2013: Powershell Stop permission inheritance after creating a new site

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

As the question basically says, is there a way to stop permissions inheritance after create a new website using powershell? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Since SharePoint 2013/Online supports a [several sets of APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164060.aspx), it depends which API you prefer:

- CSOM
- REST
- SharePoint Web Sevices

### How to break permissions inheritance for web site using CSOM

> Prerequisite: download and install [SharePoint Online Client
>   Components SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038)

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime")


Function Get-ClientContext([string]$Url,[string]$UserName,[string]$Password)
{
    $SecurePassword = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
    $context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Url)
    $context.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName, $SecurePassword)
    return $context
}



Function Web-BreakInheritance([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Web]$Web)
{
     $Web.BreakRoleInheritance($true, $false)
     $Web.Context.ExecuteQuery()
}
```

Usage

How to break permissions inheritance for Blogs site:

```
$UserName = "jdoe@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
$Password = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the password"    
$Url = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/blog"

$context = Get-ClientContext -Url $Url -UserName $UserName -Password $Password
Web-BreakInheritance -Web $context.Web
$context.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 0):

Their is no easy way to break the inheritance in SPO as limited number of powershell cmdlt avaiable. 
Check this one : http://sharepointweblog.blogspot.com/2015/03/office-365-create-site-using-custom.html

But their is one custom script written for lists,
You have to tweak this solution and run it after new site created.

Powershell script to break inherited permissions for all SharePoint Online lists in a site collection.  Before you run it, you have to modify one last line of the script!https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Break-inheritance-for-all-ded251fa

```
function Set-SPOListBreakRoleInheritance
{

   param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=1)]
        [string]$Username,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=2)]
        [string]$Url,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=3)]
        [string]$AdminPassword,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,Position=4)]
        [bool]$IncludeSubsites=$false
        )



   $password = ConvertTo-SecureString -string $AdminPassword -AsPlainText -Force
  $ctx=New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Url)
  $ctx.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Username, $password)
  $ctx.Load($ctx.Web.Lists)
  $ctx.Load($ctx.Web)
  $ctx.Load($ctx.Web.Webs)
  $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
  Write-Host 
  Write-Host $ctx.Url -BackgroundColor White -ForegroundColor DarkGreen
  foreach( $ll in $ctx.Web.Lists)
  {

        $ll.BreakRoleInheritance($true, $false)
    $ll.Update()

        try
        {
        $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
        Write-Host "Removed inherited permissions for " $ll.Title
        }
        catch
        {
        Write-Host "Failed to remove permissions for " $ll.Title
        }



        }









  if($ctx.Web.Webs.Count -gt 0 -and $IncludeSubsites)
  {
    for($i=0; $i -lt $ctx.Web.Webs.Count ; $i++)
    {
        Set-SPOListBreakRoleInheritance -Url ($ctx.Web.Webs[$i].Url) -Username $Username -AdminPassword $AdminPassword -IncludeSubsites $IncludeSubsites
    }

  }


  }


# Paths to SDK. Please verify location on your computer.
Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll" 
Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll" 



Set-SPOListBreakRoleInheritance -Username "trial@trialtrial123.onmicrosoft.com" -Url "https://trialtrial123.sharepoint.com" -AdminPassword "Pass" -IncludeSubsites $false
```

Comment: This will work for on prem but the question was for SP Online (I think)

Comment: this is for SPO.

Comment: It is now that you have changed it yes...

Answer (score 0):

There is a property you can pass called UseSamePermissionsAsParentSite

```
$newWeb = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.WebCreationInformation
$newWeb.Url = 'someURL'
$newWeb.UseSamePermissionsAsParentSite = $false
$newWeb.Title = 'Some Web'
$newWeb.WebTemplate = "STS#0"
$spWeb = $ctx.Web.Webs.Add($newWeb)
$ctx.Load($spWeb)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```